# Can't print the size of a hash of hashes or access element within it

Tags: perl

I have a hash `%AllData` pulling data from database using following code:

```
while(my $Row = $sth1->fetchrow_hashref())
        {
            if(defined($Row->{LotID}))
            {
                    $AllData->{$Row->{LotID}}->{$Row->{Name}} = $Row->{Details};
            }
        }
```

After I'm done with pulling data, I use `print Dumper($AllData);` to print out All my data which show like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4197359' => {
                         'Short Description' => 'Rock Picker',
                         'Lot Number' => '1065',
                         'Description' => 'Rock Picker'
                       },
          '4194148' => {
                         'Short Description' => 'Large work bench w/ drawers',
                         'Lot Number' => '1041',
                         'Description' => 'Large work bench w/ drawers'
                       },
          '4200944' => {
                         'Lot Number' => '1084',
                         'Description' => 'Horse Trailer'
                       }
}
```

However, when I try to print out the size of the hash or use `foreach` to access the hash, it shows 0 size and can't access any element within the hash:

```
print "Hash Size: ", scalar keys %AllData, "\n";
```

shows:

```
Hash Size: 0
```

What's the cause of my problem?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 6):

There is no hash `%AllData`, and if your program didn't raise an error then you haven't got

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the head of you program. This is *vital for all* Perl programs, especially when you are asking others for help with your code.

The hash you're interested in is the one referenced by `$AllData`, so you need to use this variable and dereference it. Like this

```
print "Hash Size: ", scalar keys %$AllData, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to dereference $AllData, now I can access it without problem. Didn't fully understand how perl deal with reference and dereference. Thought it works like C++.

Answer (score 4):

Try accessing `scalar keys %$AllData` in order to access the hash that the reference.. refers to.

- `$AllData` (what you're passing to `Dumper()` ) is a *reference* to a hash (a 'hashref')
- `%AllData` is a different thing to Perl than `$AllData`.  If this hasn't been set yet and perl isn't complaining, you may need to try putting `use strict;` at the top of your script so that you can be warned of these (and other) types of errors.

Comment: Thank you for explain this. I now know how perl deal with reference different from C++.

Comment: Yeah, those sigils (the characters $, %, and for arrays, @) can be weird at first, but once you 'get it' they're pretty useful.

Comment: ..and * for what are called 'globs', but nobody uses that (by which I mean *I* don't.)  :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to dereference the hash first:

```
print "Hash Size: ", scalar keys %{ $AllData }, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

should represent a hash ref as `$%hash` instead of `%hash` to print